# Insert PDF File in Oracle Database using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, pdf, insert, blob

I am working on a project in which I need the system to Upload/Attach a PDF file along with each record.

I have created the following form to complete this task:

[PDF file upload form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXz1u.jpg)

As you can see, the first 2 textboxes are number & varchar2, while the third text box is for the PDF file path.
Now, the only problem I am having is when I select the pdf file and get the file path, I really don't how to insert the PDF file into the Oracle database.

Can anyone assist? I need the best way of storing PDF files into Oracle Blob columns in which the database performance do not get affected.

Below is my Post button Code in which i am getting the error:

```
 Dim qry As String = "INSERT INTO PDFTABLE (id, caption, pdf) VALUES ('" & IDTextBox1.Text & "' , '" & CaptionTextBox2.Text & "' , '" & PDFTextBox3.Text & "' )"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(qry, ConString)
    ConString.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ConString.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Success !")
```

The error I am getting is:

{"ORA-01465: invalid hex number"}

There might be another way of doing it and I am not aware of it, please be specific if there is. Appreciated.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: The first thing to do is to learn how to use [parameters in ADO.NET](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).  It is essential when saving binary data but should be used for all data types anyway. Once you know how to do that, you need to pass a `Byte` array as the value for your file data. How you get that array depends on the specifics of your application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. Will do work on learning how to use parameters. Hope to come back with a solution. Thanks again!